# Transform xml notes into html footnotes

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to transform notes in XML to footnotes in HTML. The following script does the work quite OK:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:note">
        <sup>
            <a>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:text>#note</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@n" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="@n" />
            </a>
        </sup>
    </xsl:template>
```

However, the footnote should also appear in the HTML footer together with the information captured in the note tag in the XML. I can't get this working. Should I write another template which I apply in the footer element at the top of my XSL file, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="/tei:TEI">
        <html>
            <head>
                <!-- Transform teiHeader elements -->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:teiHeader"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:standOff"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <hr />
                <!-- Transform text elements -->
                <p><h2>Transcription</h2></p><xsl:apply-templates select="tei:text"/>
            </body>
            <footer>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:text/tei:body/tei:p/tei:footer"/>
            </footer>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
```

And if so, what should this template look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you need to use `apply-templates` twice, and if you want the second to produce a different output than the first for your notes, then you need to use a mode for the `apply-templates` and the relevant matching templates, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#modes.